# Changing environment version aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

How do I change php version of environment in Elastic beanstalk? When creating environment, you can select only php 7 with a promise "PHP 7.0 (this can be updated after initial setup", but later the button to change it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

According to the note [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-console.html#environments-dashboard-config), you can't change it, unless a new version comes out. So that means you can't change it, you can only update it.